# Сортировка данных при работе с jsoup (Java)

Tags: java, jsoup

**Задача :**
Вывести на экран список из 10 городов с текущей температурой окружающей среды.
Список вывести по алфавиту.
Отдельно вывести список городов, где сейчас идет снег(или дождь, или пасмурно,
или солнечно).
Также вести на экран сколько времени выполнялась программа

Что требуется : Чтобы в выводе сортировка городов выполнялась по алфавиту.

**Мой код :**

```
package devjatnadcat;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Devjatnadcat1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        long m = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://travel.ru/weather/russia/").get();
        Elements trElements = doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("class", "b-table_row b-forecast");

        trElements.forEach(trElement -> {
            // выбираем элементы по классу b-table_cell
            Elements elementsByClass = trElement.getElementsByClass("b-table_cell");
            // первая колонка - Город
            System.out.print(elementsByClass.get(0).text() + " ");
            // Парсим вторую колонку
            Element element = elementsByClass.get(1);
            // температура
            String temp = element.getElementsByClass("b-forecast_temp").text();
            System.out.println(temp);
        });
        System.out.println("");

        trElements.forEach(trElement -> {
            // выбираем элементы по классу b-table_cell
            Elements elementsByClass = trElement.getElementsByClass("b-table_cell");
            // первая колонка - Город
            System.out.print(elementsByClass.get(0).text() + " - ");
            // Парсим вторую колонку
            Element element = elementsByClass.get(1);
            // осадки
            String precipitation = element.getElementsByClass("b-forecast_description").text();
            System.out.println(precipitation);
        });

        System.out.println("Время выполнения : " + ((double) (System.currentTimeMillis() - m)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Были идейки чтобы сохранять в переменные массива строку первой колонки,но не удалось(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Изучите пакет java.util. Там есть все, что нужно

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Devjatnadcat1 {
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {

        long m = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<City> cities = new ArrayList<>();
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://travel.ru/weather/russia/").get();
        Elements trElements = doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("class", "b-table_row b-forecast");

        trElements.forEach(trElement -> {
            // выбираем элементы по классу b-table_cell
            Elements elementsByClass = trElement.getElementsByClass("b-table_cell");
            // первая колонка - Город
            String name = elementsByClass.get(0).text();
            // Парсим вторую колонку
            Element element = elementsByClass.get(1);
            // температура
            String temperature = element.getElementsByClass("b-forecast_temp").text();
            // осадки
            String precipitation = element.getElementsByClass("b-forecast_description").text();
            cities.add(new City(name, temperature, precipitation));
        });

        Collections.sort(cities);

        cities.forEach(city -> System.out.println(city.toTemperature()));
        System.out.println();
        cities.forEach(city -> System.out.println(city.toForecast()));
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Время выполнения : " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - m) + "мс");
    }
}

class City implements Comparable<City> {
    private String name;
    private String temperature;
    private String forecast;

    public City(String name, String temperature, String forecast) {
        this.name = name;
        this.temperature = temperature;
        this.forecast = forecast;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(City o) { return name.compareTo(o.name); }

    public String toTemperature() { return name + " " + temperature; }

    public String toForecast() { return name + " - " + forecast; }
}
```

Comment: у вас артефакты при запуске...

Comment: City {name='Армавир', temperature='+2 / -1', forecast='облачно с прояснениями'}
City {name='Выборг', temperature='+3 / +3', forecast='облачно'}
City {name='Иркутск', temperature='-11 / -21', forecast='переменная облачность'}
City {name='Красная Поляна', temperature='+8 / -2', forecast='облачно'}
City {name='Мурманск', temperature='-3 / -6', forecast='снегопад'}
City {name='Ростов Великий', temperature='-2 / -2', forecast='облачно'}
City {name='Салехард', temperature='-25 / -32', forecast='переменная облачность'}

Comment: @МаратЗимнуров какие артефакты?

Comment: что-то пошло не так

Comment: @МаратЗимнуров посмотрите на метод 'toString'- это не артефакты это стандартная реализация от IDEA.

Comment: есть иной вариант решения?

Comment: к примеру в массив закидывать?

Comment: Чем этот не подходит? Он не сортирует?

Comment: вывод страшный и пугающий(

Comment: @МаратЗимнуров у вас вопрос про сортировку. Мой код сортирует? По алфавиту?

Comment: комментарии для чего созданы?Для конкретного уточнения и пожеланий по улучшению кода.

Comment: да,Ваш код сортирует. Но эта "станд.реализация.от IDEA" не устраивает глаз.

Comment: @МаратЗимнуров поменяйте метод toString и/или добавьте getterов и выводите в любом формате.

Comment: с массивом реализовать возможно?

Comment: если да,то как присваивать элементам массива имена городов?

Comment: разобрал Ваш код,всё готово) пусть страшно,но готово,внизу прикреплю)

Comment: если мой код подходит, то принимайте ответ. если нет, то скажи, чем не подходит?

Comment: @МаратЗимнуров исправил код так как описано в вопросе.

Comment: @МаратЗимнуров у вас есть замечания по коду?

Answer (score -2):

```
/*
*Вывести на экран список из 10 городов с текущей температурой окружающей среды.
Список вывести по алфавиту.
Отдельно вывести список городов, где сейчас идет снег(или дождь, или пасмурно, или солнечно).
Также вести на экран сколько времени выполнялась программа
*/

package devjatnadcat;

/**
 *
 * @author Марат
 */

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Devjatnadcat1 {
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        long m = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<City> cities = new ArrayList<>();
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://travel.ru/weather/russia/").get();
        Elements trElements = doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("class", "b-table_row b-forecast");

        trElements.forEach(trElement -> {
        // выбираем элементы по классу b-table_cell
        Elements elementsByClass = trElement.getElementsByClass("b-table_cell");
        // первая колонка - Город
        String name = elementsByClass.get(0).text();
        // Парсим вторую колонку
        Element element = elementsByClass.get(1);
        // температура
        String temperature = element.getElementsByClass("b-forecast_temp").text();
        // осадки
        String precipitation = element.getElementsByClass("b-forecast_description").text();
        cities.add(new City(name, temperature, precipitation));
        });

        Collections.sort(cities);

        cities.forEach(System.out::println);

        System.out.println(" ");

        trElements.forEach(trElement ->{
        Elements elementsByClass = trElement.getElementsByClass("b-table_cell");
        // выбираем элементы по классу b-table_cell
        System.out.print(elementsByClass.get(0).text() + " - "); 
        // первая колонка - Город

        // Парсим вторую колонку
        Element element = elementsByClass.get(1);
        String temp = element.getElementsByClass("b-forecast_temp").text(); 
        // температура
        String precipitation = element.getElementsByClass("b-forecast_description").text(); 
        // осадки
        System.out.println(precipitation);
        });

        System.out.println("Время выполнения : " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - m) + "мс");
    }
}

class City implements Comparable<City> {
    private String name;
    private String temperature;
    private String forecast;

    public City(String name, String temperature, String forecast) {
        this.name = name;
        this.temperature = temperature;
        this.forecast = forecast;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(City o) {
        return name.compareTo(o.name);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  name + " " + temperature + " ";

    }
}
```

Comment: зачем вы 2 раза делаете одно и тоже? когда мой это уже делает.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman в задании два вывода)

Comment: вы два раза разбираете один и тот же кусок страницы. мой вариант делает это в один проход.